# Python - How to put sqlite result into a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sqlite

I'm trying to take an sqlite result at put it into a list for further use, but im getting a TypeError: an integer is required error, cant I just make an array where ID = 1 and flowpump = on and so on? In PHP that is an easy task, but in python I cant seem to make it Work :( I get the error in the first insert line: dbarray.insert('id',row['id'])

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("/mnt/ramdisk/heatcontroldb.db")
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT id, timeout, time, setby, vvbvalve, vvbflowvalve, flowpump, vvbsettemp, sunflowsettemp from status where id = 1")
for row in curs:
    print row['id']
    dbarray.insert('id',row['id'])
    dbarray.insert('timeout',row['timeout'])
    dbarray.insert('time',row['time'])
    dbarray.insert('setby',row['setby'])
    dbarray.insert('vvbvalve',row['vvbvalve'])
    dbarray.insert('vvbflowvalve',row['vvbflowvalve'])
    dbarray.insert('flowpump',row['flowpump'])
    dbarray.insert('vvbsettemp',row['vvbsettemp'])
    dbarray.insert('sunflowsettemp',row['sunflowsettemp'])
```

Can anyone help a python newbe? :)

Kind regards
Morten

Comment: What's `dbarray` supposed to be? Have you tried just `dbarray = list(curs)` if you want a list of DB rows

Comment: It was suppose to be an array, but i found dictonary instead: dbdict = {'id': row['id'], 'timeout': row['timeout'], 'time': row['time'], 'setby': row['setby'], 'vvbvalve': row['vvbvalve'], 'vvbflowvalve':row['vvbflowvalve'], 'flowpump':row['flowpump'], 'vvbsettemp':row['vvbsettemp'], 'sunflowsettemp':row['sunflowsettemp']}; And that Works like a charm :)

Comment: There's a much easier way to create a `dict` from it if that's what you wanted... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a pure dict from the result, then instead of all that typing, do:

```
dbdict = dict(zip(row.keys(), row))
```

This also has the advantage that `row.keys()` will correspond to the columns in the SELECT statement. Note that it does require the `sqlite3.Row` row factory to be in use.

Comment: Cool thanks, that worked like a charm :D Its allways hard to learn all the shorcuts of a new language :D